# Cakephp control when model associations are pulled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have inherited a project that is using Cakephp 2.0 and Angular for various things and I was looking up how to do joins and and Model associations.

I have a model that has associations to the users table like so

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Booking extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Trainer' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'to_user'
        ),
        'Participant' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user'
        )
    );

}
```

This works. However I have concerns about speed and security of always getting all the user table every time you access a booking. Much of the data is passed to angular and then displayed via javascript and I have found a few places were the program is passing the results of model searches directly to angular then letting it handle disseminating that data. I worry that if I add in these associations then somewhere I may now be passing out my user table into javascript which would include sensitive data.

I am wondering if it is possible to add associations at runtime via using a function call. eg.

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Booking extends AppModel {

    public function getUserInfo(){
        $this->$belongsTo = array(
            'Trainer' => array(
                'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'to_user'
            ),
            'Participant' => array(
                'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'user'
            )
        );
    }

}
```

Then in a controller use:

```
$this->loadModel("Booking");
$this->Booking->getUserInfo();
```

This is aimed so you have control over whether the associated tables are being pulled as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [Create Associations on the Fly](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly) as follows,

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Booking extends AppModel {

    public function getUserInfo(){
    $this->bindModel(
        array('belongsTo' => array(
                'Trainer' => array(
                    'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'to_user')),
            'Participant'=> array(
                'className' => 'User',
                    'foreignKey' => 'user' ) )
            );
    return $this->find('all');

    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the whitespace in the answer.